# TextTrimming to visibility convertor for wpf textbox

Tags: c#, wpf

I need to show the tooltip for textbox when the textbox text is trimmed. I have trimmed the textbox text using the following convertor.

```
 public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
 {
     string text = values[0].ToString();
     double width = Double.Parse(values[1].ToString());           
     TextBlock tb = new TextBlock();
     StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
     foreach (char c in text)
     {
         sb.Append(c);
         tb.Text = sb.ToString();
         tb.Measure(new Size(Double.PositiveInfinity, Double.PositiveInfinity));
         if (width < tb.DesiredSize.Width + 170)
         {
             sb.Append("...");
             break;
          }
      }
      return sb.ToString();

 }
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: I need to enable the tool tip for wpf text box  when the text is trimmed.

Comment: I'd make another converter that sets the tooltip of the textbox.

Answer (score -1):

Just make another converter that returns a boolean, true if the text had to be trimmed or false if not, according to your specifications in the converter you posted.  (or whatever type of property you want to bind to instead of a boolean, not sure what you want to set here)